# Is there a way to use terraform (or another IaC solution) to create the remote secrets for a multi-primary deployment of Istio?

Tags: istio

We use terraform to deploy our infrastructure in AWS.  I can find ways to setup everything else required for a [multi-primary deployment](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/multi-primary/) of Istio.  It seems like the remote secret created by istioctl to [enable service discovery across clusters](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/multi-primary/#enable-endpoint-discovery) is something close to a `kubectl` config file embedded in a `Secret`.  The only documentation of this structure seems to be in the code of `istioctl`.

Is there a way to generate this secret manually so that it can be included in the IaC deployment of the rest of the mesh?

Comment: Can you figure out what type of secret Istio creates, if it's like a hash/crypto function by inspecting the Kubernetes secret?

Comment: It seems that Istio uses service account tokens according to this file https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/istioctl/pkg/multicluster/remote_secret.go, so in theory, you could manage them using the Terraform Kubernetes provider.